# /questions/tagged/{tags} - tags param clarification

Tags: discussion, documentation, parameters

**This API method has been removed as of Jul 16 '10. The original question is preserved below for posterity.**

> It is not clear what a "list" of `{tags}` looks like.
>
> Does this parameter follow the semicolon-separated list format of the `id` parameter? Is it a comma separated list?

Comment: it should be noted that this method has been removed

Comment: @phsr and good riddance.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.

Currently `{tags}` is a space delimited set of tag names.  It really ought to be a semicolon delimited set.

So, the next code push will switch to the semicolon behavior.  The documentation will be updated to reflect this.

---

This code has been deployed now.

Comment: that is good. I can now push tags into the params ctor for that route as it is essentially the 'id'.

Comment: The documentation for the /questions route isn't clear on what the delimiter is. It just says "List of tags questions must have" So the delimiter is officially changed to semicolon?

Comment: @lfoust - yes, the semicolon is the universal unordered set delimiter.

Comment: are you going to update the docs to reflect this?